# Wordpress on App Engine Flexi - (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

Following the steps to install Wordpress on App Engine Flexible environment, however, I'm running into an issue when deploying. It works fine in the local environment.

Seem to have searched everywhere but just can't seem to find a solution. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
2018-02-17 15:12:54,539 DEBUG    root            Operation [apps/wordpress/operations/d62e4e97-31af-48c0-b82d-25bdd7317c7d] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "user": "email@domain.co.uk", 
        "target": "apps/wordpress/services/default/versions/20180217t150918", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1.OperationMetadataV1", 
        "insertTime": "2018-02-17T15:11:42.864Z", 
        "method": "google.appengine.v1.Versions.CreateVersion"
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "apps/wordpress/operations/d62e4e97-31af-48c0-b82d-25bdd7317c7d", 
    "error": {
        "message": "An internal error occurred during deployment.", 
        "code": 13
    }
}
2018-02-17 15:12:54,542 DEBUG    root            (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\cli.py", line 797, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\calliope\backend.py", line 757, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\surface\app\deploy.py", line 74, in Run
    parallel_build=False)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 588, in RunDeploy
    flex_image_build_option=flex_image_build_option)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\command_lib\app\deploy_util.py", line 394, in Deploy
    extra_config_settings)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\appengine_api_client.py", line 187, in DeployService
    message=message)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 246, in WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=retry_interval)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 266, in WaitFor
    sleep_ms=sleep_ms)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\util\retry.py", line 226, in RetryOnResult
    if not should_retry(result, state):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\util\waiter.py", line 260, in _IsNotDone
    return not poller.IsDone(operation)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\api_lib\app\operations_util.py", line 171, in IsDone
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
2018-02-17 15:12:54,542 ERROR    root            (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] An internal error occurred during deployment.
2018-02-17 15:12:54,819 DEBUG    root            Metrics reporting process started...
```

Answer (score 2):

This is often related to a malformed `app.yaml` file when used in deployment. Things like specifying a 5GB disk in `env: flex` when 10GB is min size.

Conflicting stanzas may also cause this.

Another example is that you are currently limited to 6GB storage per CPU core. So if you specify 1 CPU and 10GB, you will get `Error Response: [13]`

We've also witnessed this on Mac OS, related to `Icon` files in the deployment dir. Able to be resolved by deleting the files:
`find . -name 'Icon?' -type f -delete`

https://issuetracker.google.com/72873974

If you are willing, post your app.yaml (redacting any PII).

Comment: how can I change flex environment variable to edit 5GB limit? I opened app.yaml with nano but couldnot ckeck the env: flex limit